# How to force a service (bash script) to read from stdin (ask me to input something) when the script is executing?

Tags: linux, bash, systemd

I created a service with systemd that uses wendy (inotify replacement tool) to listen in a directory and run a bash script when something changes.

however, my script relies on stdin at a certain time to read a variable. but when the service runs it skips asking me in a terminal for the input entirely and proceeds with the rest of the bash script.

i'm new to systemd and services, is there anyway I can force it to ask me for input?

this is what happened from /var/log/syslog

Oct 7 21:52:09 server wendy.sh[13062]: was added to scripts.

Oct 7 21:52:09 server wendy.sh[13062]: enter scriptname: (/home/user/scripts/blah.sh)

Oct 7 21:52:09 server wendy.sh[13062]: chmod: missing operand after +x

Oct 7 21:52:09 server wendy.sh[13062]: Try 'chmod --help' for more information.

it was supposed to ask me for a scriptname to pass into chmod.

How to accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: 1) Consider behaviour of `read v </dev/null`. 2) Ask yourself how the service should know which of the many `/dev/tty*`, `/dev/pts/*`, graphical interfaces, etc, it should use for input.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is very difficult to ask for user inputs in a script running as a background task, because they have no terminal attached. I would advise you to try to find an alternative to reading inputs from stdin.

If you really want to achieve that, you could for example run a program somewhere that will listen to a UNIX socket, and your automated script could communicate to this client to ask for an input (c.f. [this Stack Exchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26715/how-can-i-communicate-with-a-unix-domain-socket-via-the-shell-on-debian-squeeze)).

> With netcat-openbsd, there is a -U option. If you don't have it, you probably have netcat-traditional installed instead; I'd suggest switching.
>
> Example command: nc -U /var/run/socket